# How to make parts of navigation appear using Grav

Tags: css, twig, styling, grav, text-styling

I'm working with Grav for the first time, so the Twig Sytnax etc. is still very new for me.
I should style the navigation so that first a part of the word or the page name is displayed
and with onhover the rest of the word should appear. (Example: You can see "Ab", with onhover "About").

I'm not sure how to access the names of the individual pages and divide them.  As I understood it, the navigation.html.twig pulls the name and the links of the individual pages. How can I divide these names individually? Is it best if I write my own static navigation so that I can edit the individual names individually? How would I do that?

Code: navigation.html.twig

```
    {% macro loop(page) %}
{% for p in page.children.visible %}
    {% set current_page = (p.active or p.activeChild) ? 'active' : '' %}
    {% if p.children.visible.count > 0 %}
            <a class="has-children sidebar-nav-item {{current_page }}" href="{{ p.url }}">
                {% if p.header.icon %}<i class="fa fa-{{ p.header.icon }}"></i>{% endif %}
                {{ p.menu }}
            </a>
            <a>
                {{ _self.loop(p) }}
            </a>
    {% else %}
            <a class="sidebar-nav-item {{ current_page }}" href="{{ p.url }}">
                {{ p.menu }}
            </a>
        </a>
    {% endif %}
{% endfor %}

{% endmacro %}

{% if theme_config.dropdown.enabled %}
    {{ _self.loop(pages) }}
{% else %}
    {% for page in pages.children.visible %}
        {% set current_page = (page.active or page.activeChild) ? 'selected' : '' %}
        <a class="sidebar-nav-item {{current_page}}" href="{{ page.url }}">
                {{ page.menu }}
            </a>

    {% endfor %}
{% endif %}
{% for mitem in site.menu %}
        <a class="sidebar-nav-item" href="{{ mitem.url }}">
            {{ mitem.text }}
        </a>
{% endfor %}
```

Code sidebar.html.twig:

```
    <nav class="sidebar-nav">
      {% include 'partials/navigation.html.twig'%}
    </nav>
```

Answer (score 0):

The above navigation loop assumes you're nesting/arranging the pages as you want to have them in the navigation. It will then put the top level/root pages as the first "level" of navigation and any children of that page will appear in the sub navigation below the parent, assuming your theme has `dropdown.enabled` (`{% if theme_config.dropdown.enabled %}`) and the child page is set to visible. This will also do this recursively, so if the children also have children, they will be included as well.

If you structure your site according to this way, you will achieve the desired navigation.

There are alternative ways to create a different navigation using a custom configuration in the theme. If you'd like more help with that, I can point you in the right direction.